# CAN bus on bread board without 120 ohm terminating resistors?

Tags: stm32, can

I have developed a CAN bus between two STM32s on two breadboards. My transceivers are MCP2551 ICs. I have faced something weird, the transfer of data becomes possible only when I remove two 120 Ohm terminating resistors. This made me curious to explore the reason of it. Please share your Ideas. Thank you.

Comment: do the transceivers have them built in?

Comment: @jsotola Yep. They do. Sounds like an answer to me. The datasheet has a block diagram on the first page. I find that rather surprisingly actually since that would not allow the transceiver to be used at anything but the ends of the bus. It's not even advertised in the datasheet anywhere. It just discretely appears in the block diagram.

Comment: @DKNguyen no they are not the termination resistors. See electrical specs for their value. That's why they are not advertised.

Comment: other thought: wire wound termination resistors

Comment: @Justme Huh. I guess they're not. I don't really get why they are there though. On the block diagram it is listed as an actual component but in the electrical specs it is listed more like just a measurement of parasitics.

Comment: It could be anything. We don't know what voltages you use, how are the breadboards constructed, and how they are connected together. Do they even share a ground reference?

Comment: @Justme: Two boards share the same Ground. Supply Voltage of Transceivers are 5.5 and 5 Volts.

Comment: Here comes this question to my mind, whether two terminating resisteors are needed in short distances.

Comment: @Bornak They're not, but I don't see why having them would stop it from working. They aren't detrimental so much as the issues they address aren't severe enough to prevent functionality at short distances.

Comment: @DKNguyen Maybe those are pull resistors ensuring a 2.5V idle voltage (recessive state). My take is that this is what "0.5 VDD" above the op amp refers to.

Comment: Please post your schematic. Where exactly did you place the resistors? You do absolutely need two 120ohm terminating resistors when using MPC2551 or any other transceiver, so the problem isn't related to them, if they are placed correctly. For example, if you incorrectly place pull resistors on the Rx/Tx lines, this can pull the whole CAN bus into bus off fault state.

Answer (score -1):

most CAN transceivers use internal voltage dividers to handle bus voltages far below and far above the GND/VDD region.

Those resistors will not be 120 ohms.